# How update the whole values of an Auto-increment column in MySQl table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, auto-increment

I copy a table from another table in MySQL by considering some condition for inserting in new table. One the column of these tables is  defined as a *Auto-Increment* column which is caused a problem for me.The following table is my new table however, the new table id is not start from 1 to 5.

```
       +---------+---------+-----------+
    -> | id      | type    | superType |
    -> +---------+---------+-----------+
    -> | 1210435 | /m/019_ | /m/0kpyln |
    -> |  776693 | /m/01m9 | /m/014s   |
    -> |  682533 | /m/01mh | /m/014s   |
    -> |  764776 | /m/01mp | /m/014s   |
    -> |  685170 | /m/01n7 | /m/014s   |
    -> +---------+---------+-----------+
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you use a script to copy the records between the tables?

Comment: Try: first truncate the current table and use INSERT..SELECT command eg. `INSERT INTO new_table (type, superType) SELECT type, superType FROM old_table`

Comment: @KaeL I use copy command and then insert command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to use script for copy data from one table to another instead of copy/paste
see below syntax, it will take care of identity column(Auto incremented)

```
INSERT INTO table_name1(fields you want)  SELECT fields you want FROM table_name2
```